# Android application memory usage keeps growing

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-studio

I am using android studio, and I have two issues that might be related. The core problem is that the memory increases with each fragment/ListView I navigate to and doesn't decreases even after quitting the app.

1. My app has a service with a running thread that keeps running in background to measure and store data usage. Even though I made sure of closing all cursors/database connections, the memory usage of my app keeps increasing over time (from 25mb to 50-60mb).
2. after each launch, the memory increases by up to 20mb and doesn't decrease after exiting the app, see the screenshots

[image: Screenshot]

I am using 'MPAndroidChart' and 'Android-CircleProgressIndicator' libs.

I've tried DDMS but didn't help. I've tried allocation tracking, but no matter the changes I made, it keeps listing apps threads

Comment: I am actually using android studio. I've tried allocation tracking, but no matter the changes I made, it keeps listing apps threads.

Comment: Whats the Service? Post the code if you think it's the problem.